# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

I am trying to show my variables values to view page, but it's showing the error of trying to get property of non-object. Please someone help me.
Here is my Controller-

```
public function myAffiliates(Request $request) {
    if ($user_id = Sentinel::getUser()->id) {
        $affiliates = DB::table('affiliate_users')
          ->where('affiliate_users.user_id', $user_id)
          ->first();
    }
    //dd($affiliates);
    return view('dashboard.affiliates.show',['affiliates' => $affiliates]);
}
```

And I wrote to my view page like this-

```
@foreach ($affiliates as $affiliate)
    <ul>
        <li>First Upline - {{ $affiliate->first_upline_id }} Pts,</li>
        <li>Second Upline - {{ $affiliate->second_upline_id }} Pts,</li>
        <li>Third Upline - {{ $affiliate->third_upline_id }} Pts.</li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're only returning 1 affiliate, so you're attempting to iterate through the object's properties. Either remove the foreach and pass `['affiliate' => $affiliates]` (get rid of the s on the key), or change `first()` to `get()`.

Comment: the error message is a big clue as to what's happening. take a step back and learn to understand the error messages. but not just, understand the words, but what they mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `first()` to retrieve a single object

use `get()` to retrieve collection and iterate it on your blade

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate on object's properties try this

```
<ul>
        <li>First Upline - {{ $affiliates->first_upline_id }} Pts,</li>
        <li>Second Upline - {{ $affiliates->second_upline_id }} Pts,</li>
        <li>Third Upline - {{ $affiliates->third_upline_id }} Pts.</li>
</ul>
```